# How to send multiple input values with same class name or id via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to send multiple input values via AJAX to my PHP script. It's working fine when I use `getElementById`. However I have the option to add a child. It iterates the input fields, then I get values only from the first child. I tried to use `getElementsByClassName` but it gives values as `undefined`. This is my code:

```html
<div id="name-field" class="name-field row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Name of child</label>
      <input id="firstname" class="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
      <input type="text" class="date" id="thedate" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="addChild" name="addchild" class="btn-success">Add Child</a>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn" onclick="btnSubmit('step1')">Next Step</a>
```

```js
//Iterate child function
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#addChild").click(function() {
    $(".name-field:first").clone().find("input").val("").end()
      .removeAttr("id")
      .appendTo("#additionalselects")
      .append($('<a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'));
  });
  $("body").on('click', ".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest(".name-field").remove();
  });
});

//Sending values function
function btnSubmit(step) {
  //Set Var with Name
  //Set Var with DoB
  if (step == 'step1') {

    //values using ID
    var Name = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var DoB = document.getElementById("thedate").value;

    //Values using classname
    var Name = document.getElementsByClassName("firstname").value;
    var DoB = document.getElementsByClassName("date").value;

    //Create a Variable catVar Having the Var Name and Var DoB Concatinated with a --

    var stepVar = Name + "--" + DoB;

    $(".thevoornaam, .date").each(function() {
      alert();
    });
  } else {

  }
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {



    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "validations/btnSubmit.php?q=" + step + "&q2=" + stepVar, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to achieve with this, if I did't explain it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `date` input has `date` class name but you are looking for `thedate`. Also, `getElementsByClassName` return an array of matched elements so you have to iterate through instead of trying to get `.value`

Comment: i also have thedate ID, i wrote my both code targeting id and class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jQuery you can do it in this way.

```
var firstname = [];
$("#name-field .firstname").each(function(){
 firstname.push($(this).val());
});
```

In firstname you will all the values.

### Update

Here is a working pen.

https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/dmvwVB

Comment: i tried to use like this, but not working.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stepname").click(function(){
        var firstname = [];
        $(".firstname").each(function(){
         firstname.push($(this).val());
        });
    });
});

Comment: Forgot you are adding div dynamically, please see updated answer. Give $("#name-field .firstname").each

Comment: @SmitRaval  So glad I found this. This is really the best way to achieve simply getting just the input values. I was doing something similar, but I was doing $('.className').each(function(i, val){ array.push(val);}  The values were in there, but there was a ton of random dom gibberish I didn't need.  This simply allowed me to capture only the input vals. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("firstname")
```

returns an array... so the following will give you the elements value with index i. To get all the values you will need to do a ForEach.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("firstname")[0].value
```

Since you're using JQuery elsewhere, why not use...

```
$('.firstname')[0].val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most ideal way to do this is :

- add a form wrapper to your fields (`id="ajaxForm"`)
- to have a `name` to all your form
  fields and use the below code to generate the `data` to be passed to
  your AJAX call

`$("#ajaxForm").serialize()`

The return value of `$.serialize()` can be directly used as the `data` for the ajax call

```js
$("#ajaxForm").on("submit", function () {
  var ajaxData = $("#ajaxForm").serialize();
  
  $("#ajaxData").text(ajaxData);
  
  
  $.ajax({
    url:"",
    type: "get",
    data : ajaxData,
    success: function (resp) {}
  });
  console.log(ajaxData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="return false" >
  <input id="firstname" class="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />
  <input type="text" name="date" class="date" id="date" />
  
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div id="ajaxData"></div>
```